# Kubuntu installation - Failed to create a file system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, kubuntu

I tried installing Kubuntu using the manual partition option. When I get to the point where the installer tries to create the new partition, I get the following error:

"Failed to create a file system - The EFI file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0)(sda) failed."

I don't think it is a hard disk failure because I can create a new partition using Windows. The Windows is installed on a SSD and I'm trying to install Kubuntu on a clean HDD. Secure boot is turned off, fast boot is turned off and the SATA mode is set on AHCI.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `lsblk` and of `sudo parted --list`, both formatted as code, i.e. with a line consisting of three backticks ``` before and after.

Comment: I am not sure, but it is possible that during installation your installation medium (a USB stick?) was `/dev/sda` (since you booted from it), and you should have partitioned `/dev/sdb`.